# How to use autoprefixer with Gulp?

Tags: gulp, autoprefixer, gulp-autoprefixer

I am trying this code on the gulpfile.js and it generates the directory and file but does not add the prefixes shown on the autoprefixer website. What am I doing wrong?

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

exports.styles = () => (
    gulp.src('css/styles.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
);
```

Comment: try adding a browser list in your package.json
"browserslist": [
        "last 15 versions",
        "> 1%"
    ],
for demo => https://github.com/Mohamed-Talaat333/gulp-boilerplate